# 404 not found on API route for MEAN application?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http-post, http-status-code-404

In my application when one of the forms is submitted, this function is called...

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.message = "";
    var params = {
        ...
    };
    Subscriber.create(params)
        .success(function(data) {
            ...
        });
};
```

Which in turn calls this subFactory create method, which posts to '/mail'.

```
subFactory.create = function(subData) {
    return $http.post('/mail', subData);
};
```

Upon attempting to post to '/mail' I get this error `POST http://localhost:8080/mail 404 (Not Found)`. Which I cannot figure out how to resolve because I have this...

```
apiRouter.route('/mail')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        ...
    });
```

And as far as I'm aware I should be able to find '/mail'. The full apiRouter is located [here](https://github.com/jonwrona/Table-Tome/blob/master/app/routes/api.js), and the full server.js file is located [here](https://github.com/jonwrona/Table-Tome/blob/master/server.js).

Comment: How are you using `apiRouter`? expand out your sample server code a bit.

Comment: @KevinB I added a link to the apiRouter file on my github repo if that isn't too much.

Comment: You should be posting to `/api/mail` because of `app.use('/api', apiRoutes);` *(server.js)* For completeness, can you include that portion of server.js in your question while i put together an answer?

Comment: Sure thanks that was a huge oversight for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you setup your api routes in server.js, you routed it to `/api`, so all routes added to your router will begin there. Therefore, your `/mail` route is located at `/api/mail`

**server.js**

```
// ROUTES
// ========

// API ROUTE
// -------------
var apiRoutes = require('./app/routes/api')(app, express);
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

**./app/routes/api**

```
apiRouter.route('/mail')
    .post(function(req, res) {
```